# static_cast<int>(abs(13200 / 1.1)) = 11999

Tags: c++

Вопрос в том почему

```
static_cast<int>(abs(13200 / 1.1)) = 11999
```

а

```
static_cast<int>(abs(12000.)) = 12000
```

Comment: Прочитайте - https://habr.com/ru/post/112953/ там все есть

Comment: тогда почему 13200 / 1.1 = 12000
судя по логике работы программы сначала считается то что в скобках т.е.
static_cast<int>(abs(13200 / 1.1)) == static_cast<int>(abs(12000.))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Беда в том, что знаменатель `1.1` не может быть представлен в формате IEEE-754 точно, он будет округлён к ближайшему значению, равному `1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625` (`0x3ff199999999999a`), которое чуть-чуть больше. По этой причине после деления получится число чуть чуть меньше `12'000`, и вы берёте от него целую часть, получаете `11'999`

И хотя я согласен, что это очень тупо, когда константы на этапе компиляции вычисляются не точно, всё-таки придётся пока что с этим жить. Таково наследие сурового прошлого в программировании.

Comment: Благодарю за полный ответ

Answer (score 7):

Потому что на самом деле это число - `11999.99999999999818...`

Добро пожаловать в мир вычислений с плавающей точкой! :)

Здесь нет точного представления, здесь любое число - просто сумма степеней 2 - типа, 2 + 1/2 + 1/16 +...

Comment: [Гордо] Вот и я обзавелся персональным минусатором :)

Comment: Поправите, поставлю + (ничего личного, ответ очень сырой)

Comment: На самом деле это очень бредовая фишка многих компиляторов - вычислять константы по тем же правилам, по которым работает сама программа. Я убеждён, что все константы на этапе компиляции обязаны вычисляться с абсолютной точностью и ОДИН раз потом округляться.

Comment: @Zealint И тем самым получить расхождение между одними и теми же вычислениями во время выполнения и во время компиляции? Нет уж, ненавижу двойные стандарты :)

Comment: это зависит от специфики задач, которые вы решаете, а не от двойственности стандартов. Мне лично нужно, чтобы константы вычислялись точно, то есть воспринимались как числа с бесконечной точностью, а не как числа, которыми оперирует компьютер. Иными словами, не существует констант разного типа, они все одного типа - рациональные дроби бесконечной точности (не зависимо от способа записи). А вот программа должна выполняться по правилам тех типов, которые в ней используются. К сожалению, во всех существующих языках даже это условие не выполнено полностью.